# De l'origine de clef et de clé

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

Savez-vous quelle est l’étymologie de *clé* et *clef* et comment en est-on arrivés à avoir les deux mots en usage ?

Sont-ils parfaitement interchangeables ? Il me semble qu'il le sont, mais voyez-vous des cas où l'un est préférable à l'autre ?

Comment: Ce qui est bien avec une **clef** et une cage, c'est qu'on peut enfermer un **cerf** par ce **bief**.

Comment: Pour ma part, je pense que "clef usb" écrit de cette manière prête à sourire

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Le *f* est une scorie de la racine latine (*clavis*). La graphie « clé » est plus récente et a été forgée à partir de l'ancien pluriel qui n'avait pas de *f*.

Encore une fois  *Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey, nous donne des détails :

> Le mot est apparu d'abord sous la forme *clef* (1080), du latin clavis « clef, loquet, barre ».
>   À l'origine le mot était synonyme de *clavus* (−>clou), car la serure primitive consistait en un clou ou une cheville passé dans un anneau; la différenciation sémantique des deux mots a accompagné des innovations techniques. Le mot pourrait être apparenté ou emprunté au grec *klaïs*, en tout cas il appartient à un groupe de mots techniques à base *clau-* exprimant l'idée de « fermeture » (−> clore, clou), et ses dérivé sont bien latins (−> cheville, clavicule, conclave). La graphie *clé* (v. 1121) est due à la réfection d'un singulier sur l'ancien pluriel *clez, cles* (1130-1140), d'où le *f* étymologique (du *v* latin) avait disparu.

Je ne connais pas de différence dans l'emploi de l'un ou de l'autre de nos jours.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ces lumières ! Je n'avais jamais fait attention à la similarité avec _clavus_.

Comment: Est-ce que c'est la même idée de clou qui a donné écrou et écrouer?

Comment: @mouviciel Non. Un écrou sur un boulon vient du latin *scrofa* (truie, vulve). Un écrou dans une prison vient apparemment du francique *skrôda* (morceau, d'où morceau de papier puis procès-verbal). (Sources: TLF, Petit Robert.)

Answer (score 8):

Le TLF n'a qu'[une entrée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/clef) pour les deux orthographes, ce qui tend à montrer qu'elles sont parfaitement interchangeables.

La section prononciation et orthographe (à la fin) précise que le F n'est jamais prononcé et semble indiquer que la forme plurielle ancienne ne prenait pas de f, ce qui peut expliquer qu'il ait disparu de la forme singulière également.

Je pense surtout que le choix de l'un ou de l'autre est une question de mode, et on peut constater que [clé prend nettement l'avantage sur ces 50 dernières années](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cl%C3%A9%2Cclef&year_start=1500&year_end=2011&corpus=7&smoothing=3), sans doute parce qu'il est plus en accord avec sa prononciation.

Answer (score 2):

L'[OQLF](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) suggère, de [préférer la forme la plus simple, la plus française et la plus claire lorsqu'il y a deux graphies possible pour un mot.](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4736) Il recommande *clé* plutôt que *clef*.

Comment: Merci @Gilles pour la précision.